# SQL filter with AND rule spanning multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlperformance

I have a MySQL database which looks something like:

```
item table
| id | name |

item_category link table
| item_id | category_id |

category table
| id | name |
```

If I want to fetch items that are related to one of many categories I can simply do:

```
SELECT item.*
FROM item
JOIN item_category ON item_category.item_id = item.id
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = item_category.category_id
WHERE category.name in ("category_one", "category_two")
```

However, if I want to get items which are related to *all* of a list of categories then the problem becomes a little more complicated because the rows returned from my query contain a single category each. How can I write a query which contains only the items which are related to *all* categories?

I tried writing a query with a nested select like this:

```
SELECT item.*
FROM item
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT item.id
  FROM item_category ON item_category.item_id = item.id
  LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = item_category.category_id
  WHERE item_category.id = item.id
  AND category.name = "category_one"  
)
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT item.id
  FROM item_category ON item_category.item_id = item.id
  LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = item_category.category_id
  WHERE item_category.id = item.id
  AND category.name = "category_two"  
)
```

But this is incredibly unperformant even with indexes on the relevant fields.

Thank you for any input on this issue.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Additionally, questions about query performance ALWAYS require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, together with the result of the EXPLAIN.

Comment: Incidentally, `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x = ...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical ways to do this are to either (1) join to the "category" cable once for each value that must be matched, or (2) aggregate your first query (grouping on item) and filter where `count(distinct category.name)` = number of items in your value list.

Comment: `ALL` is a special case though, isn't it?

Comment: If he meant all categories that exist, yes; but I took it to mean all categories in the list.

Comment: I see, yes - perhaps I misinterpreted

Comment: Yes, I meant all categories in the list. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is a good solution. My query is still slow but the duration has been halved using this approach. Thanks!

Comment: @WilliamCarter One trick is to do (2); but defer joining to the items table until after the aggregation (i.e. aggregate in a subquery to get the item_id values, then join that subquery to the items table).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category;

CREATE TABLE category
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO category VALUES
(101,'animals'),
(102,'minerals'),
(103,'vegetables');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item_category;

CREATE TABLE item_category
(item_id INT NOT NULL
,category_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(item_id,category_id)
);

INSERT INTO item_category VALUES
(1,101),
(1,102),
(1,103),
(2,102),
(3,101),
(3,103);
```

By inspection, we can see that only item 1 is associated with all categories.

So, how do we select those items that aren't?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ic.item_id 
           FROM item_category ic 
           JOIN category c ON c.id <> ic.category_id 
           LEFT 
           JOIN item_category x 
             ON x.item_id = ic.item_id 
            AND x.category_id = c.id 
          WHERE x.item_id IS NULL;
+---------+
| item_id |
+---------+
|       2 |
|       3 |
+---------+
```

The list of items pertaining to ALL categories, is the inverse of this set.